# Having problem with putting values into ranges

Tags: sql

I have the following statement

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN response BETWEEN 0 AND 5 then '0 - 5'
WHEN response BETWEEN 6 AND 10 then '6 - 10'
else 'over 10'
end AS 'range',
COUNT(*) as 'count'
FROM((SELECT datediff(MIN(referral_interventions.dateOfintervention), referral.referralDate) as response

from referral

LEFT JOIN referral_interventions on referral.refid =referral_interventions.refID
LEFT JOIN interventions on referral_interventions.typeOfintervention = interventions.intid

WHERE referral.referralDate > '2021-11-01'
GROUP BY referral.refid)
AS tempdiff)
GROUP BY 'range';
```

The select statement within the first FROM works and produces 119 results with response ranging from 0 to 12.
The full statement produces all 119 showing as

```
range      count
0 - 5       119
```

Any ideas wher my syntax etc might be wrong

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and your code is invalid standard SQL. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

Sorted

I changed ' to ` around range and count